# Insert Slider value into the form field

Tags: jquery

I am using the slider from jQuery UI and would like to insert the slider value into the form. How do I actually do that? Below is the code snippet for my form.

Thanks.

```
$("#slider").slider({ max: 200000,step:50, 
    change: function(event, ui) {
        $('what_to_insert_here').empty().append(ui.value);
    }
});

<form action='/submit' method="POST">
    <div class = 'form'>
        <label>SliderValue:</label>
        <input type="text" name="Value" > </input>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit!" />
</form>
```

Comment: What is "the jQUery slider?" Also, we need to see some jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then you have two steps to fulfill:

1. Change `<input type="text" name="Value" > </input>` to `<input type="text" name="Value"/>`. The `input` tag has no closing tag.
2. Change your jQuery to the following:

   ```
   $("#slider").slider({
       max: 200000,
       step:50, 
       change: function(event, ui) {
           $(".form input[name='Value']").val( ui.value );
       }
   });
   ```

What we do with the jQuery is set the `value` attribute of the `input` element inside the div with the class `form` to whatever `ui.value` equals.

Comment: the submit button is an input also... need more specific selector

Comment: @charlietfl: Look carefully. The submit button is not inside the div with the class `form`.

Comment: Thanks! It works. By the way, I have a few input tag in my form, now all of them are filled up with the slider value. How do I actually differentiate it so that the slider value only goes to the input tag named value?

Comment: @revolver: Use this selector instead: `$(".form input[name='Value']")`.

Comment: Hi, if I want to post the value of slider as a form params directly, how should I do that?